# How do I prove that the inductive sequence $y_{n+1}= \dfrac {2y_n + 3}{4}$ is bounded . $y(1)=1$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

How do I prove  that the inductive sequence $y_{n+1}= \dfrac {2y_n + 3}{4}$ is bounded? $y(1)=1$

**Attempt:**  Let us assume that the given sequence is unbounded. :

Then, $y_{n+1} \rightarrow \infty$ either for some finite $n$ or when $n \rightarrow \infty$

> CASE $1 :$ When $|y_n| \rightarrow \infty$ at a finite $n$

Since : $y_{n}= \dfrac {2y_{n-1} + 3}{4}$, then $y_n \rightarrow \pm \infty \implies y_{n-1} \rightarrow  \pm \infty \implies y_{n-2} \rightarrow  \pm \infty ~~\cdots$

This ultimately means $y_2 \rightarrow  \pm \infty$ which is not true.

Hence, there does not exist a finite $n$ for which $y_n \rightarrow  \pm \infty$.

> CASE $2:$ When $|y_n| \rightarrow \infty$ at $n \rightarrow \infty$

I think we can proceed the same way as we did above, i.e inductively, we proceed like above and deduce that if the above assumption is true, then $y_2 \rightarrow \infty$, which is not true.

Is my attempt correct?

Does there exist a proof without induction as well?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are using induction above? It is a little hard to avoid induction of some sort as the sequence is defined by induction.

Comment: @copper.hat Sorry, was a typo . I was attempting to prove without and with induction. However, I wasn't able to make an attempt without induction. Edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An unbounded sequence need not diverge to $\infty$, even if its values are positive.

---

If the sequence converges, then its limit $l$ satisfies
$$
l=\frac{2l+3}{4}
$$
so $l=3/2$. We could try proving that $y_n\le 3$ for all $n$. The base case is clear, so assume that $y_n\le 3$ and try to prove that $y_{n+1}\le 3$ without peeking below.

> We have $2y_n+3\le 2\cdot3+3=9$, which implies $y_{n+1}\le\dfrac{9}{4}<3.$

The bound below is also easy: $y_n>0$, for all $n$.

Comment: @VHP Next prove that the sequence is increasing, so it indeed converges to $3/2$.

Comment: Okay .. Here's an attempt.. I am afraid though that at this moment, I can think of the inductive method only .. Given that $y_{n+1} = (2y_n+3)/4 \implies y_n = (2 y_{n-1} + 3)/4$

 

Hence, $y_{n+1}-y_n = \dfrac {y_n-y_{n-1} } {2}$ and $y_{n}-y_{n-1} = \dfrac {y_{n-1}-y_{n-2} } {2}$ and so on ...$\\$

Continuing in this fashion, we obtain $y_{n+1}-y_n = \dfrac {y_2-y_1 } {2^k} >0$ for some $k$. $\\$

Hence, $y_{n+1} > y_n~\forall~n$ . Hence, $Y$ is monotonically increasing. 

Am I Correct?

Comment: @VHP If $y_{n}<y_{n+1}$, then $2y_n+3<2y_{n+1}+3$. Moreover, $y_2=(2+3)/5=5/4>1$ (base step).

Comment: Ohh! Wow... yeah.!

Answer (score 3):

It is clear that $y_n\gt 0$ for all $n$. Let us prove by induction that $y_n\lt 4$. This is certainly true if $n=1$. And if $y_n\lt 4$, then $\frac{2y_n+3}{4}\lt 4$.

There are smaller upper bounds than $4$, but to prove boundedness we need not find the least upper bound.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You are welcome. I should have used $17$ instead of $4$, to stress that if we pick $M$ not too small, the induction proof for $y_n\lt M$ goes through smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

$$|y_{n+1}-y_n|=\frac{1}{2}|y_n-y_{n-1}|=\frac{1}{2^n}|y_0-y_1|$$

then 
$$|y_n-y_{n+r}|\leq |y_n-y_{n+1}|+|y_{n+1}-y_{n+2}|+...+|y_{n+r-1}-y_{n+r}|=\frac{1}{2^n}|y_0-y_1|\sum_{k=0}^r\frac{1}{2^k}=\frac{1}{2^n}\underset{n\to\infty }{\longrightarrow } 0$$

Then $(y_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, and so it converge. You can conclude that $(y_n)$ is bounded.